# Change start of threaded text path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

I created a series of semi-circle paths in Illustrator and linked them together using the Threaded Text function. Using the Type on a Path options, I was able to flip the direction of the text to the order I'd like. But I would like to flip the order of the path, all together. Right now, the type begins at the outside of the circle and works its way inwards. I want the type to start on the inside of the circle and work its way outwards. How would I accomplish this?

Here's what my path looks like:

[image: Threaded type path]

Again, I want the type to start at the top of the rings, not at the bottom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the threaded text objects is controlled by the **stacking order of the objects** themselves.

The **backmost** object is used **first** in the thread. The **frontmost** object is used **last** in the thread. So, to reverse the order of the text threading, reverse the stacking of the thread objects. Simply highlight the objects in the **Layer Panel** and choose **Reverse Order** from the **Layer Panel menu**.

**You MUST set the stacking order BEFORE you add text threading.** This is the annoying aspect of it. If you've already created the threaded text object and added type, it won't reverse. You have to set up the stacking order **before** ever converting things to threaded text objects. If you've already got text and threading in place, I'm unaware of any command which will reverse the threading *after* the fact. Such a command may exist, I just don't know about it.